# Two increasing functions from the set of positive integers to the set of positive integers such that neither f (n) is O(g(n)) nor g(n) is O(f (n))

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics

Here is the question again : Give an example of two increasing functions f (n) and g(n) from the set of positive integers to the set of positive integers such that neither f (n) is O(g(n)) nor g(n) is O(f (n)).

I tried with several functions such as sine and cosine, but they are not increasing functions but Oscillatory. Then I tried x + sinx and x + cosx. However for sufficiently large coefficients c and n0, they also fail two satisfy the criteria. I am starting to doubt if such pairs of functions even exist !?

Answer (score 3):

Take $f(n) = (2\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor+1)!$ and $g(n) = (2\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil)!$.

For example:
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
n&1&2&3&4&5 \\\hline
f(n)& 1! & 3! & 3! & 5! & 5! \\\hline
g(n)& 2! & 2! & 4! & 4! & 6!
\end{array}
$$
We have
$$
\frac{f(2m)}{g(2m)} = \frac{(2m+1)!}{(2m)!} = 2m+1 \to \infty
$$
as well as
$$
\frac{f(2m+1)}{g(2m+1)} = \frac{(2m+1)!}{(2m+2)!} = \frac{1}{2m+2} \to 0.
$$

Comment: Quite a clever and elegant answer, mixing the properties of floor, ceil and factorials ! Would have never thought of such stuff

Comment: All of these are red herrings. The idea is that you have a "race" between two functions. They take turns to overtake each other by a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Totally inelegant approach:

Start with f, g = 0.  Increase f by 3, g by 1, until f(n) >= 2 g(n). Then increase f by 1, g by 4, until g(n) >= 3f(n). Then increase f by 5, g by 1 until f(n) >= 4 g(n) etc.

Comment: While this is an answer, it's quite a pain to write such answer in notations and make someone understand with proofs xD

Comment: Sandler, what’s the problem? Many functions are hard to write down explicitly. And it catches the essence of the problem: f must grow until it exceeds g. Then g must grow until it exceeds f. Then f must grow until it exceeds g more. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider $f,g$
$$f(x)= \begin{cases}{}
k^{2k}, & x\in(2k,2k+1)\\ 
k^{2k+1}, & x\in(2k+1,2k+2)
\end{cases} \\
g(x)= \begin{cases}{}
k^{2k-2}, & x\in(2k,2k+1)\\ 
k^{2k+2}, & x\in(2k+1,2k+2)
\end{cases} \\
 $$
for $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Does the answer apply for a fixed k? In that case, the functions do not cover the set of all positive integers

Comment: @Sandler2k1. From right hand of values, is corresponding interval, where $k \in \mathbb{N}$ or you are asking something other? Anyway add to answer for clarity.

Comment: Oh I get it now, Thanks for the edit!